# JLabel does not move in java

Tags: java, swing

I can't seem to change the position of a JLabel in java (swing). I have tried referencing documentation but nothing works. The label is always stuck to the left side of the screen. Here is my code:

```
package com.company;

import java.awt.*;
import javax.accessibility.Accessible;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Main {
    public static class Window {
        int labelWidth = 30;
        int labelHeight = 30;

        public void createWindow(int width, int height) {
            JFrame window = new JFrame("Student Management");
            window.setSize(width, height);
            window.setVisible(true);
            window.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);

            window.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

            JLabel loginLabel = new JLabel("Login To System");
            loginLabel.setVisible(true);
            loginLabel.setBounds(width/2-labelWidth/2, 0, labelWidth, labelHeight);

            window.getContentPane().add(loginLabel);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Window win = new Window();
        win.createWindow(500, 500);
    }
}
```

Comment: Similar questions on this site: [java swing cannot set position of component site:stackoverflow.com](https://www.google.com/search?q=java+swing+cannot+set+position+of+component+site:stackoverflow.com)

Comment: TL/DR: 1. to set absolute position, use null layouts. 2. But having said that, I strongly urge you ***not*** to use null layouts or set absolute positions but instead learn and use the [Swing Layout Managers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html) as this will bring you much more robust and flexible GUI code as well as GUI's that work on a wide variety of platforms as expected.

Comment: You are attempting to display the label horizontally centered at the top of the frame. So the first change is to use: `add(loginLabel, BorderLayout.PAGE_START)`.  This will display the label at the top. Next task is to center the text. There are two approaches: 1) tell the label to center the text in the available space by using: `loginLabel.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER)` or 2) use a "wrapper" panel. That is create a JPanel using a FlowLayout with center alignment. Add the label to the panel and the panel to the frame.

Comment: (1+) By the way good [mre]. Also note that components should be added to the frame BEFORE the frame is made visible. This will make sure the layout manager is invoked. There is no need to make the label visible, it is visible by default.

Comment: Thank you everybody who contributed to this post. I have now successfully place my label where I need it! (thanks to Swing Layout Managers).